# Why did LaTeX formula formatting stop working?

Tags: support, bug, formatting

On [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93720/how-vulnerable-to-physical-hits-are-federation-ships/93747#93747), I tried using the LaTeX formula formatting to prettify it.

However, formula formatting no longer seems to work.

For instance, I wrote $ \Delta V $ into it and get the text you see, while I expected the capital version of the Greek letter "Delta" followed by the letter "V".

When and why did this stop working.  What do I use instead?

Comment: You could just use the ascii symbols for Δv

Comment: @Richard nitpick: Δ is only in unicode, not ASCII.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I pride myself on not knowing the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, it never worked on this SE site.  It's something that's enabled on a per-site basis by Stack Exchange.  We don't really need it like other sites (e.g. Math), so it's not enabled here.

Comment: That's correct.